# Performance Of One Row With Total Vs Multiple Rows with Seperate Values?

Tags: database-design, sqlite

Not 100% sure how to explain this situation but here it goes:

I am building an Inventory Database that all items received are entered into and a label is created for each Container, that is going to have bar code to tie the physical items to the records in the database.

So, every Container will have a label, and is usually a child of a received order.

Currently the label has a bar code that contains the Qty of Product that Container represents AND the RowID of the received record.

The question is what is best practice:

1. Have one row per received Order that contains a TotalProductQty for
   the ENTIRE received order and total Containers Recevied. Then have
   the labels on the Container have the RowID and that specific
   ContainerQty. Then the Table is updated with a UsedQty Column with
   the Qty of the Product that is within the Container being used
   (based on the ContainerQty embedded in the barcode). Also, a column
   with UsedContainersQty, but do not have any record in the system at
   a container level.
2. Would I be better off to just enter each container into its own row
   and add a Used Bool column? This would clearly make quicker updates,
   but would also make the table MUCH larger and would (I would think)
   slow down the inserts and possible effect performance with selects
   because a received order will then go from 1 insert/Row To select to
   anywhere from 5 to 50?
3. I was also wonder if it would at all make sense to leave the
   ReceivedOrders Table as is with TotalProductQty and ProductID and
   ContainerQty then create a new table for each container in a
   ReceivedContainers Table that would have a foreign Key to the
   ReceivedOrders Table and a row for each container that can be tied
   to the labels.

These are the best options I can think of implementing but I don't have the slightest clue as to what one will give the best performance?

Not sure if performance is effected by the language the native app is written in or not so I have also tagged the applications language and platform also.

As an example if I followed method one I would have one table like so:

```
RowId|TotalProductReceived|TotalContainersReceveived|UsedProductQty| UsedContainerQty |ProductTypeID|VendorID|ReceivedDate|LastUsedDate
1    |        225         |            5            |     100      |        2         |     1       |    1   | 3/31/2014  |  4/1/2014
```

This shows that I have 5 Containers with a total of 225 items. and that 2 of the containers have been used totaling 100 items. So I have a remaining balance of 125 items being stored in 3 containers. Each container has a label on the container with a Comma seperated barcode containing the RowID (in this case it is 1) and the Qty in the container, when that barcode is scanned the Row with RowID 1 is updated with UsedContainerQty = UsedContainerQty + 1 and UsedProductQty = UsedProductQty + Quantityembedded in barcode.

The pros I see with the above is it is a much more compact database, easy to query and should perform much faster then the next examples, the problem is that it leaves a lot of gap in information.

Option 2 would be more like the following:

```
ContainerId|ProductQtyInContainer|ProductTypeID|VendorID|ReceivedDate|Used
1          |        50           |     1       |   1    | 3/31/2014  |4/1/2014
2          |        50           |     1       |   1    | 3/31/2014  |4/1/2014
3          |        50           |     1       |   1    | 3/31/2014  |null
4          |        50           |     1       |   1    | 3/31/2014  |null
5          |        25           |     1       |   1    | 3/31/2014  |null
```

Then the container would have a single barcode with only the ContainerID on it when entered would update the Used column with the date it was used, un used items would be null.

This would provide more indepth analysation of how often products are used and more info on each container, but at the cost of being much bigger with not only many more rows but also much more redundant info:

To Fix the Redudent info my idea was possible split the data over 2 tables:

the first like:

```
RecevedID|ReceivedDate|ProductTypeID|VendorID
    1    | 3/31/2014  |     1       |   1
```

then the second like:

```
RecevedID|ContainerId|ProductQtyInContainer|Used
    1    |    1      |        50           |4/1/2014
    1    |    2      |        50           |4/1/2014
    1    |    3      |        50           |null
    1    |    4      |        50           |null
    1    |    5      |        25           |null
```

this one seems to have less redundant info but will require more complex inserts and I fear concurrency issues with this method. Long Inserts locking the DB while other try to update form there end?

I am just unsure what methods and practices are best and most useful?

the scope of this app will be to enter every item that enters the building have a digital record of it and label each item with a in house only scannable ID that when a product is used can be scanned to update the records so we can have a better over view of how much of each item we use over a specific time period and to also be able to look into what we currently have in stock.

But I fear to many deadlocks with the items coming in and items be scanned out and not sure what method above will best help avoid info loss. and failed record updates. Yet still offer all the benefits of total inventory control and knowledge!

reports will also be made multiple times a day from the information also.

Any help is GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: it's too abstract, can you give a concrete example with data (not loads, but just enough) to make it clear what options (1), (2), and (3) represent

Comment: @I.K. I have updated my question, hopefully to a helpable state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used SQLite for this kind of application, so there may be some specific SQLite limitations I'm not aware of, but in general I'd recommend building a normalized schema first, focusing on making it easy to understand and hard to break.

I'd then recommend building test scripts to see if you can meet your anticipated performance goals; if you can't, there are lots of ways to optimize a database before you denormalize. This forces you to quantify your concerns - are you worried about tens, hundreds, thousands of products? How many transactions do you expect per year? How many concurrent users? It also forces you to think through likely usage scenarios - which queries are you likely to need? This really helps think through your design, and allows you to identify scenarios to worry about - your fear of deadlocks is reasonable, but they are nearly always caused by slow queries - avoid them, and your database shouldn't lock.

Write a test harness to run your queries against a representative set of test data - if you anticipate needing a million transaction records, populate a database with 3 million test records.

Only once you've proven you have a problem with performance would I look at denormalizing and going for more esoteric solutions.

So, in your case, I'd recommend using a fairly standard way of managing inventory data - with a transaction table. A transaction basically means a container coming in, a container being used, or a container being found empty/deficient after being checked in.

For example:

```
TransactionQuantity|ContainerId|ProductTypeID|VendorID|TransactionDate|Comment
                 50|          1|            1|       1|      3/31/2014|Container received
                 50|          2|            1|       1|      3/31/2014|Container received
                -50|          2|            1|       1|       1/4/2014|Container used
```

This schema has the benefit of telling you what happened to each container, and when; it allows you to deal with partial usage, and it allows you to use `sum(transactionQuantity)` to find out what the stock level is; by using the transaction date column, you can also easily see the stock levels at any point in the past, by using simple SQL.

The table does get long - but as long as you're using indexes, long tables aren't a particular problem with SQL as long as you don't go into extremes; depending on the database engine and hardware, tens of millions of rows are not extreme.